# Multiple el in Backbone.View

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

For example i have:

```
Job.Views.Response = Backbone.View.extend({
el: '.ra-response-button',
    events: {
      "click" : "alert"
    },

    alert: function() {
       console.log(this.$el);
    }; 
)};
```

And i have multiple buttons (BUTTON).
I want that work only with clicked button. How i can do that?

Answer (score 2):

Change the `el` to the parent element of the buttons, then do something like this

```
 <div id="buttonWrapper">
    <input type="button" id="button1" />
    ... snip ...
 </div>
```

View:

```
  Job.Views.Response = Backbone.View.extend({
     el: 'buttonWrapper',
     events: {
      'click #button1': 'eventHandler1', 
      'click #button2': 'eventHandler2',
      ... And so on...
   }
```

Comment: I can have 25-100 buttons on page

Comment: Then use the `body` as the element.

Comment: And if your buttons are in various place, set a specific class to them to better find them.

Comment: Set a specific class and add a `data-something` attribute to the buttons, then in the click handler read the `data` attribute and fire the corresponding method.

Comment: If you are expecting to have 25-100 buttons, then you should set the events to be: events: { 'click button': 'onButtonClick' }
By doing so, onButtonClick will be fired for each of your buttons and in your event object, you will be able to look at the id, name, class, or any other attribute of the specific button that was clicked.